# Verstecken vs verbergen

Tags: word-choice, synonym

Nach Duden:

> **verstecken:** in, unter, hinter etwas anderem verbergen
>
> **verbergen:** 
> 1a. den Blicken anderer entziehen; verstecken 
> 1b. nicht sehen lassen, verdecken
> 2a. der Kenntnis, dem Wissen anderer vorenthalten, entziehen; verheimlichen 
> 2b. für Eingeweihte erkennbar sein

Gibt es denn einen Unterschied zwischen den Verben?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"verstecken" hat erdnahen Charakter. Kinder verstecken sich beim Spielen. An Ostern werden Ostereier im Haus oder Garten versteckt.

"Verbergen" ist stilistisch eine Ebene höher. Der Sprecher war hinter einem Vorhang verborgen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich denke, dass sich *verstecken* (im täglichen Sprachgebrauch) wirklich mehr auf reale Objekte (insbesondere Gegenstände) bezieht. *Verbergen* kann sich, wie 2a. im Duden vorschlägt, auch auf Gedanken etc. beziehen, d. h. im Sinne von *verheimlichen*.